# Is there a way to make a panel draw graphics by calling it from another class

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, panel

I am writing a program which sorts through data in `.csv` files, and then displays that data in a bar graph that has to be drawn using `System.Drawing`.

At the moment, the program will read the file, sort out the data required, and then the panel will call the variable, which it should use to set the height of the rectangle, only the panel will remain blank after the program has sorted out the data.

I need a way to call the panel once the variables have been updated so that the new variables will adjust the height of the rectangle.

using `Refresh()` does not redraw anything on the panel.

I understand it could be a problem with my code elsewhere but I need to at least make sure its not anything to do with the panel before I search through everything else. The code for the panel is written below;

```
    public void GraphPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // double variables for the graph creation

        double janGraph;

        double febGraph;

        double marGraph;

        double aprGraph;

        double mayGraph;

        double junGraph;

        double julGraph;

        double augGraph;

        double sepGraph;

        double octGraph;

        double novGraph;

        double decGraph;

        janGraph = DataSorter.GetJan;   // get the graph data for January

        febGraph = DataSorter.GetFeb;   // get the graph data for February

        marGraph = DataSorter.GetMar;   // get the graph data for March

        aprGraph = DataSorter.GetApr;   // get the graph data for April

        mayGraph = DataSorter.GetMay;   // get the graph data for May

        junGraph = DataSorter.GetJun;   // get the graph data for June

        julGraph = DataSorter.GetJul;   // get the graph data for July

        augGraph = DataSorter.GetAug;   // get the graph data for August

        sepGraph = DataSorter.GetSep;   // get the graph data for September

        octGraph = DataSorter.GetOct;   // get the graph data for October

        novGraph = DataSorter.GetNov;   // get the graph data for November

        decGraph = DataSorter.GetDec;   // get the graph data for December


        Brush graphBrush;   // declare the brush used for drawing the graph bars

        Color graphColor;   // declare the colour for the graph

        graphColor = Color.Blue;    // set the colour for the graph

        using (Graphics graphPanel = GraphPanel.CreateGraphics())    
        {

            graphBrush = new SolidBrush(graphColor);    // set up the brush that will draw the bars for the graph

            // draw bar for january                

            graphPanel.FillRectangle(graphBrush, 48, 520, 48, Convert.ToSingle(janGraph));



        }
```

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is (almost) always the wrong way to draw.  Use the paint event or an actual report tool.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: To build on the previous comment: not only is `CreateGraphics()` the wrong thing to do, it's _especially_ pointless and wrong in a `Paint` event handler. Use the `e.Graphics` object passed to your handler.